# Video QML type crashes (0xC0000005: Access violation) when loading .avi file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qml, qtmultimedia

I am experiencing app crashes due to a Access violation when trying to load a file with the Video QML Type. I am running a C++/Qt 11.1 application on Windows, using msvc2017 compiler.

I am currently trying to render a simple video in a loop within my application using the following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtMultimedia 5.8

Video {
    id: videoPlayer
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: "C:/Users/Me/Desktop/video.avi"
    autoLoad: true
    autoPlay: false
    focus: true
    fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectFit
    loops: MediaPlayer.Infinite
    muted: true
}
```

When executing this code I am getting an exception with the following call stack:

[image: Visual Studio Callstack]

It looks like something with a signal from the QAbstractVideoSurface inside the QtMultimedia module is not working out. What I am wondering about is that this exception **does not happen always**, but only in roughly 4/5 application runs (if I turn autoLoad: false and triggering the load by a click, I sometimes works somehow). As well it **only happens in Release** build configuration.

I was already thinking about a codec issue, but I could reproduce it using different video files with different codecs.

It actually looks like a threading problem to me, but I have currently no clue how this appears as I am actually just trying to render the code above in the main UI thread.

Maybe somebody already ran in a similar or connected issue?

Thanks already!

Comment: Undefined behavior somewhere int he code, there is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Have you tried with Qt 5.11.3, which is the latest version of the 5.11 series ?

Comment: @VTT that's a QtCreator crash! Has nothing to do with the OP question.

Comment: @MassimoCallegari That's Qt bugtracker, it lists bugs for both qt libs and tools. Creator-related bug just happen to be first in the list.

Comment: @VTT so the link should be [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22QtMultimedia%20crash%22). If I click your link, it shows a QtCreator issue. Anyway, that's a pretty generic reply. It's just like saying "suit yourself"

Comment: @MassimoCallegari Your link leads to the same location as mine. And yes, this is a generic reply that directs op to location where "somebody already ran in a similar or connected issue" are gethered.

Comment: change to `file://C:/Users/Me/Desktop/video.avi`

Comment: @MassimoCallegari Did not try it with 5.11.3 but had the issue already with Qt 5.8.0. Thought is was some QT bug and used a workaround. Now after migrating I have still the same behaviour and want to solve it finally.

Comment: @eyllanesc Should not be the issue. If I use the path with the file protocol prefix I get an error in `DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource`. As well the path in the original format works in debug build configuration.